# ios like popover uitableview in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-listview

How to get floating listview on top of another activity like in android facebook app.I tried to do it but I dont know how to proceed .I reallly appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance

I am trying to create listview with toggle imagebutton on top which displays listview with linear fade down animation over already existing view .Here is a link to what I am talking about

http://handytechplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/facebook-apps-for-mobile-phones.jpg

Comment: if notification screen take all size of screen then its ok for you dear :)

Comment: Hello Bhanu.Yes but there will another mainActivity behind this one.If it shows little dark area behind this the list(notication) then it would be good.But yes it can take the entire screen also the image button in the top should toggle and display list like in facebook fade in.Thanks again Bhanu.

Comment: @BhanuSharma Yes Bhanu .Even that would be good.

Comment: This should be what you are searchinh for. Try this link: [https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView](https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView)

Answer (score 2):

Ok then if try this in same layout take one list view and its visibility gone ok 
now you code all which you want to show in that list like child view of list 
now whenever you first click on notification then  make view visible  of that list view and set adapter and whenever click on second time then view gone.

i think its work coz i also use this method earlier :)

is this helpful for u dear...

Comment: Can you paste that code for animation and the stuff you mentioned above.I would really appreciate your help.Thanks in Advance.+1 for your time.